# returning the TWO most recent entries for multiple users in one query

Tags: mysql

The code below successfully returns the most recent entry on a per user basis... but is there a simple way of modifying this to return the TWO most recent per user, or is a completely different approach required? 
Thanks.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM lms_attendance t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
                 FROM lms_attendance t2
                 WHERE t2.user = t1.user            
                 ORDER BY t2.id DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I think it's quite clear as it is. solution posted below for others.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who comes across this looking, then LIMIT 1,1 when ordering by date in the subquery seems to work... and of course changing the = to >= in the WHERE

exmaple:
SELECT t1.*
FROM lms_attendance t1
WHERE t1.id >= (SELECT t2.id
                 FROM lms_attendance t2
                 WHERE t2.user = t1.user
                 ORDER BY t2.id DESC
                 LIMIT 1,1)